# No roots plants stems from big tree

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, plant-recommendations, planting

Can any no root plant set alive by putting its bottom part inside a banana and wait for few days to see if roots comes out? Or it can happen to only specific plants and not all plants? if have a plant that has hard broad stems and no roots as i picked it from a big tree (now wanted to use as my indoor plant), can this plant be grown roots that way?

Comment: Do you mean a woody  stem, like a thin branch, from a tree? If so, no, it won't  form roots in a banana

Comment: It depends on the species. You should wrote (or make a photo) of the plant you want to root, or it will be difficult to answer (too generic o answer just too short). Look gardening books (encyclopedia-like): there should be a description of "propagation", and you will see if a part of steam could create roots, and maybe how to improve probabilities (e.g. type of cutting, flattering, ...